# call a bean method for each datatable item

Tags: java, spring, jsf

I'm facing a problem when trying to call a bean method for each item of a list displayed in a h:datatable,I get the folwing exception:

```
- INFOS: Exception when handling error trying to reset the response. javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:498)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

I have an account entity and department entity which have a common column named code, but they're not linked, so to display the department with the same code as account I use this shared attribute(code) to get the department based on account's code.

```
<h:form prependId="false"> 
   <h:dataTable id="accounts_list"  class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed" 
   var="account" value="#{AccountBean.accountProvider.allAccounts}">
      <h:column>
         <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="account type"/>
         </f:facet>
         <h:outputText value="#{account.categoy.label}"/>
      </h:column>
      <h:column>
         <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="account code"/>
         </f:facet>
         <h:outputText  value="#{account.code}"/>
      </h:column>
      <h:column>
         <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value=" department"/>
         </f:facet>
         <h:outputText  value="#{AccountBean.searchDepByAccountCode(account.code)}"/>
      </h:column>
                         .....
   </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Is it possible to proceed like that or should I search for another solution to do it.

thanks,

Comment: It's a part of business logic. What do you suppose to do if there is no such department? You can e.g. catch the exception and return empty string or "not found" string in the searchDepByAccountCode() method. You should decide it first.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem ideed, I've already checked using sql but seems like data changed since, solved the problem by a simple try catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a part of business logic. What do you suppose to do if there is no such department? You can e.g. catch the exception and return empty string or "not found" string in the searchDepByAccountCode() method.

Alternatively you can return not single result but a list of depeartment. The list could be empty of contains one or more items.